How do I find my Path to add into .env file on github when making an APP
I'm not at all sure how to add my Private keys path into the .env file in GitHub.
I managed to download a private-key.pem to my PC but have no idea how I get the path to add into it.
PRIVATE_KEY_PATH="YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY_PATH"
I was following these instructions to do this process but stuck at this stage now!(Get your app credentials and identifying information) Q:5
text
I was thinking of editing the private-key.pem in Note++ and copying what was in there into the
PRIVATE_KEY_PATH="YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY_PATH"
have not tried this though.

It is explained in the very next step. Which step are you having trouble with?

In your .env file, replace YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY_PATH with the full path to your private key, including the .pem extension. Not sure how to do this?
